# Is there a way to tell what encoding is used for the name and content of a file?

Tags: encoding, character-set

Is there a way to tell what encoding is used for the name and content of a file? Both GUI and terminal solutions (preferred) are fine. Thanks and regards!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could try

```
chardet <<<filename
```

The `chardet` program can try to *guess* the encoding of the stream on stdin, and `<<<` is the mean by which `bash` use a string as stdin, the same as

```
echo filename | chardet
```

For a whole directory content you can use

```
ls dir | chardet
```

**EDIT**

I forgot about the content, but is almost the same:

```
chardet <filename
```

or

```
cat filename | chardet
```

or for all the files in dir

```
cat dir/* | chardet
```

Comment: Thanks! Nice to know chardet. I am trying to figure out the encodings of the names of the compressed files in a zip archive, but the output by chardet seems not correct. Please see my post here http://askubuntu.com/questions/48158/chinese-encoding-in-names-of-compressed-files-in-zip . Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

If you mean mime-encoding you could try 
`file --mime-encoding filename` for the content of the file.

Comment: Thanks! How about the file name?

Comment: I never put special chars in filenames. I remember there was some command which tries to detect the encoding from a string, then you can just pipe the filename through this...

Comment: Thanks! I was wondering what differences are between "mime-encoding" and "character encoding"?