# How can I find out the encoding method that gedit uses to open a text file?

Tags: gedit, encoding

Gedit successfully guessed the correct encoding charset of a text file. I would like to find out what the charset is, but couldn't find a way in its menu. How can I do that? Thanks.

Comment: From command line `file {filename}` will show the encoding of a file

Comment: Also: http://askubuntu.com/questions/48151/is-there-a-way-to-tell-what-encoding-is-used-for-the-name-and-content-of-a-file?rq=1

Comment: @Rinzwind: I would like to know what encoding charset gedit is using to show a text file, because gedit does the right guess.

Comment: @muru: I would like to know what encoding charset gedit is using to show a text file, because gedit does the right guess.